# How to call a cell with a path and use it for a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Worksheet'!$A3 has the file path of the document I want to reference.

```
R://User/Example/[Practice.xlsx]
```

In there I want to get the sum of $F$10:$J$10 in Sheet2 of the Practice.xlsx document.

I thought below but having trouble getting it to work.

```
=SUM((Workbook'!$A3)Sheet2'!$F$10:$J$10)
```

Comment: INDIRECT: `=SUM(INDIRECT(Workbook'!$A3&"Sheet2'!$F$10:$J$10"))`  But it requires the workbook to be open.

Comment: Is there a way to do it while the workbook is closed?

Comment: not with referring to a cell with the link.  You would need to do the whole link in the sum.  INDIRECT is volatile and volatile functions do not work with closed work books.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll create a macro that'll open up the files needed then. Thanks for the input!